# Reverse proxy for nginx configuration for subpath

Tags: nginx

I currently have this configuration for a reverse proxy in nginx

```
    server {
        listen 8888 default_server;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location = / {
        try_files $uri @proxy2;
    }

    location = /redirect.html {
        try_files $uri @proxy2;
    }

    location ~ /user/(.*)$ {
        try_files index.html @proxy2;
    }

    location @proxy2 {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6079;
        max_ranges 0;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
        max_ranges 0;
    }

    location = /websockify {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
    }

}
```

My problem is that I have a url of the type `http://example.com:8888/user/username` and I need to redirect it to `localhost:6079`. Unfortunately, what is listening on port 6079 wants the URL without the `/user/username` part. It is my understanding that when I try to use this configuration, I get a flask generated 404 (the application at port 6079 is a flask app). I tried pretty much everything for the whole afternoon, including rewrite of the url, hardcoding the actual url and other tricks from the documentation of nginx, but I could not find a working solution.

Observe that if I connect directly to http://localhost:6079/ the application works fine, so it really seems to be this nginx setup.

**Edit**:

I tried to modify as suggested and add the / at the proxy2 proxy_pass line, but it complains as explained here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662940/proxy-pass-cannot-have-uri-part-in-location/21714937#21714937

As for the logs, I don't see anything unexpected, except that if I connect to localhost:8888/user/username it shows a 404, and if I connect to localhost:8888 I see the flask app.

Keep into account that the nginx is on a docker image, but I browse from the host machine, so 127.0.0.1 in the nginx is the docker instance, and when I browse 127.0.0.1 it's the host machine and the port goes through the bridge that I setup when I started the container.

**Edit 2**

Logs don't tell much.

```
172.17.42.1 - - [10/May/2016:22:14:05 +0000] "GET /user/sborini/redirect.html?width=1375&height=695 HTTP/1.1" 200 212 "http://localhost:8888/user/sborini/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
172.17.42.1 - - [10/May/2016:22:14:05 +0000] "GET /user/sborini/vnc_auto.html HTTP/1.1" 404 166 "http://localhost:8888/user/sborini/redirect.html?width=1375&height=695" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
172.17.42.1 - - [10/May/2016:22:14:57 +0000] "GET /user/sborini/vnc_auto.html HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://localhost:8888/user/sborini/redirect.html?width=1375&height=695" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
172.17.42.1 - - [10/May/2016:22:14:58 +0000] "GET /user/sborini/vnc_auto.html HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://localhost:8888/user/sborini/redirect.html?width=1375&height=695" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
172.17.42.1 - - [10/May/2016:22:18:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
```

See how I get something if I connect to the plain `/` entry
In any case, I tried a simplified case:

```
server {
    listen 8888 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

location = /user/sborini/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555;
    max_ranges 0;
}

}
```

and a netcat listening on 5555. I get a bad gateway. Investigating.

Comment: Do you need to proxy or could you forward?

Comment: @tim I need the proxy.

Comment: In your simplified case, since the request, as per the log, is `/user/sborini/vnc_auto.html`, can you please change `location = /user/sborini/ {` to `location /user/sborini/ {` ?

Answer (score 2):

Add a trailing slash to your proxy_pass directive.

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6079/;
```

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/444532/reverse-proxy-remove-subdirectory)

[Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Fingers crossed this works... took me 30 seconds on Google to work it out.

Comment: i tried that as well, did not work.

Comment: Please show the matching access logs for one request to Nginx and then proxied server. I'd like to see what request actually hits port 6079.

Comment: ok, let me check..

Comment: Ok, it's quite complicated. I revise my question to add more.

Comment: Please post actual log files, not your interpretation of the log files.

Comment: You've added Nginx logs. What we really need to see is one Nginx access log entry, along with the access log for your Flask app. However what I can see suggests that Nginx is saying 404 not found, which suggests that either there's a problem in Flask or it's not calling the proxy. That's why I wanted to see Flask logs, to see if it was hitting it at all, and if so what URL is being called.

Comment: ok. flask logs I need to find them. However, I managed to obtain something, so I am on the right track. Thank you for the rubber ducking. I'll write some more as soon as I find something definitive with the actual answer. Now I have to go to sleep because it's quite late here.